# reuse of an existing list

Tags: sharepoint, moss

is there a way to reuse an existing list in a sibling site on sharepoint?

I have an image list on a sub site and I want to be able to access parts(images) of that list from what is effectively a sub site of a sub site.

to put it simply, I want to be able to view a list without having to duplicate it and the contents of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain what do you mean by "access parts(images) of that list"?

Do you want to:

- access List Items from sub-sub-etc-webs and use it some way?
- create list in somwhere in web hierarchy that has exact or similar structure to already existing list?
- create list in somwhere in web hierarchy that has exact or similar structure to already existing list AND contains same list items?
- have a list that has some items from another list?

## Solution for displaying list items in another web.

You could use [ListViewWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.listviewwebpart_properties.aspx) and programmatically set WebId and ListName property.

However if we are not talking about programming here, then, for a simple solution, use [SharePoint Enhanced List View Web Part](http://trentacular.com/2009/08/sharepoint-enhanced-list-view-web-part/)

Comment: I want to be able to view a list without having to duplicate it and the contents of the list.

Answer (score 0):

If both sites are inside the same Site Collection, you can use a Data View Web Part (you need to use SharePoint Designer, which you can [get for free from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/spd)).

The DVWP connects to another list, and you can choose which columns you want to show. Filtering, Grouping, Sorting, and also changing the way the data is displayed are also possible.

That way, you maintain your list at one location, but you can display it at multiple sites.

More informationm about the Data View Web Part can be found on the [Microsoft website](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/CH100667641033.aspx).